# Class properties without superclass properties

Tags: python, method-resolution-order

I have an inheritance hierarchy whereby some of the classes have a class property named e.g., 'pickled'.  I would like to get `A.pickled` if it exists or None if not — even if A derives from many classes including e.g., B and `B.pickled` exists (or not).

Right now my solution crawls `A`'s `__mro__`.  I would like a cleaner solution if possible.

Comment: What problem are you trying to solve?

Comment: @IfLoop I am using the class property to automatically pickle particular properties.  I am also using another class property to automatically generate a user interface, and yet more class properties to automatically generate histories of parameter values.  Do you have a better solution?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To bypass the normal search through the `__mro__`, look directly at the attribute dictionary of the class instead. You can use the [`vars()` function](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#vars) for that:

```
return vars(cls).get('pickled', None)
```

You could just access the `__dict__` attribute directly too:

```
return cls.__dict__.get('pickled', None)
```

but using built-in functions is preferred over direct access to the double-underscored attribute dictionary.

`object.__getattribute__` is the wrong method to use for looking at class attributes; see [What is the difference between type.__getattribute__ and object.__getattribute__?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24150894/what-is-the-difference-between-type-getattribute-and-object-getattribute)

`type.__getattribute__` is what is used for attribute access on classes, but that'd still search the MRO too.

Comment: Thank you very much.  We're lucky to have you on Stackoverflow.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure, but perhaps

```
try:
    return object.__getattribute__(cls, 'pickled')
except AttributeError:
    return None
```