# What is the difference between type.__getattribute__ and object.__getattribute__?

Tags: python, getattr, python-internals, method-resolution-order

Given:

```
In [37]: class A:
   ....:     f = 1
   ....:

In [38]: class B(A):
   ....:     pass
   ....:

In [39]: getattr(B, 'f')
Out[39]: 1
```

Okay, that either calls super or crawls the mro?

```
In [40]: getattr(A, 'f')
Out[40]: 1
```

This is expected.

```
In [41]: object.__getattribute__(A, 'f')
Out[41]: 1

In [42]: object.__getattribute__(B, 'f')
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-42-de76df798d1d> in <module>()
----> 1 object.__getattribute__(B, 'f')

AttributeError: 'type' object has no attribute 'f'
```

What is getattribute not doing that getattr does?

```
In [43]: type.__getattribute__(B, 'f')
Out[43]: 1
```

What?!  `type.__getattribute__` calls super but `object`'s version doesn't?

```
In [44]: type.__getattribute__(A, 'f')
Out[44]: 1
```

Comment: @thecoder16: Python 3.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You are operating directly *on classes*. `object.__getattribute__` is only used *on instances* of `A` and `B` instead. That's because [special methods are looked up on the type](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#special-method-names); for instances the type is the class.

For classes then, the type is.. `type`:

```
>>> class A:
...     f = 1
... 
>>> class B(A):
...     pass
... 
>>> type(B)
<class 'type'>
```

so `type.__getattribute__` is used:

```
>>> type.__getattribute__(B, 'f')
1
```

and `object.__getattribute__` works fine on instances:

```
>>> object.__getattribute__(B(), 'f')
1
```

For instances attributes are looked up first on the class (in the case of [data descriptors](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/descriptor.html#descriptor-protocol)), then on the instance, then if the instance doesn't have the attribute, the class hierarchy is searched in MRO order. This is the job of `object.__getattribute__`. So `object.__getattribute__` looks at the first argument (e.g. `self`, the instance object) for the attribute, *and* at objects in `type(self).__mro__`.

For classes, attributes are looked up on the class itself and all its bases; `type.__getattribute__` looks directly at `self.__mro__` for these; `self` being a class object here.

If you use `object.__getattribute__` for *classes* then, there is no `f` attribute on `B` *directly*, and no `f` anywhere in `type(B).__mro__`. If you use `type.__getattribute__`, `A` is a member of `B.__mro__` so `f` is found there:

```
>>> type(B).__mro__
(<class 'type'>, <class 'object'>)
>>> B.__mro__
(<class '__main__.B'>, <class '__main__.A'>, <class 'object'>)
```

Comment: Would you mind explaining why object.__getattribute__(A, 'f') works then? I'm a little confused.

Comment: I'm sure you're right, but I'm still a bit lost.  What is `object.__getattribute__(B, 'f')` doing?  Is it necessarily bad code?  It might solve my other problem: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24150636/class-properties-without-superclass-properties

Comment: @Magitrek: I was getting there. Done now. `object.__getattribute__` looks for `'f'` in `self` and each of `type(self).__mro__`. For class `B`, `type(B).__mro__` is not the same thing as `B.__mro__`.

Comment: @NeilG: `object.__getattribute__` is the *wrong method* for looking at attributes on a class hierachy. Use `type.__getattribute__` instead. Or better still, just use `type(B).__getattribute__` directly and get the right special method, always.

Comment: @MartijnPieters: Thank you.  I want to know whether `B` has the attribute itself or whether it's being inherited.  Is that impossible?

Comment: @NeilG: I posted an answer on your other question too.

Comment: So when accessing `X.attr`, `object.__getattribute__` searches `X.__dict__` -> `type(X).__mro__.__dict__`, while `type.__getattribute__` searches `X.__dict__` -> `X.__mro__.__dict__` -> `type(X).__mro__.__dict__`. Am I right?

Comment: @sunqingyao: yeah; `object.__getattribute__` is for instances, `type.__getattribute__` for classes, and the latter must look for attributes on the metaclass hierarchy too.

Comment: "For instances attributes are looked up first on the class (in the case of data descriptors), then on the instance, then if the instance doesn't have the attribute, the class hierarchy is searched in MRO order. "


IMO that statement isn't completely accurate. Data descriptors are looked for on the entire MRO, not just the class. Also if instance doesn't have attribute, first non-data descriptors are searched on the entire MRO, then attributes.

Comment: "For classes, attributes are looked up on the class itself and all its bases;"
Technically data descriptors on metaclass is looked up first. Also non-data descriptors are looked up before attributes on bases